# how to do the program using subquery approach

Tags: sql, teradata

```
  SELECT SKU,  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALEDATE)=6 AND  STYPE='P'
           THEN AMT 
           END) AS VALUEJUNE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALEDATE)=7 AND  STYPE='P'
           THEN AMT 
           END) AS VALUEJULY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALEDATE)=8 AND  STYPE='P'
           THEN AMT 
           END) AS VALUEAUGUST

 ,(VALUEJUNE+VALUEJULY+VALUEAUGUST) AS totalsales
FROM TRNSACT

GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY totalsales DESC ;
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Put most of your query in a derived table, including the `GROUP BY`. Calculate totalsales on its result:

```
select sku, VALUEJUNE, VALUEJULY, VALUEAUGUST, (VALUEJUNE+VALUEJULY+VALUEAUGUST) AS totalsales
from
(
    SELECT SKU,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALEDATE)=6 AND  STYPE='P'
           THEN AMT 
           END) AS VALUEJUNE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALEDATE)=7 AND  STYPE='P'
           THEN AMT 
           END) AS VALUEJULY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SALEDATE)=8 AND  STYPE='P'
           THEN AMT 
           END) AS VALUEAUGUST
    FROM TRNSACT
    GROUP BY SKU
) dt
ORDER BY totalsales DESC ;
```